# Duda sobre revisiones a preguntas cerradas por estar basadas en opiniones

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, ediciones, revisiones

Hace unos días hice una pregunta en StackOverflow en Español que terminó cerrada por estar basada en opiniones. Creo que es la primera vez que me cierran una pregunta por este motivo. La pregunta [es esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/505623/el-preferencemanager-en-android-est%C3%A1-obsoleto-significa-que-no-funciona-en-las). El caso es que vi que puedo editar la pregunta y marcarla como:

> Esta edición resuelve el motivo de cierre original y la pregunta debe ser considerada para reabrir.

Así que eso fui lo que hice, cambié un poco la pregunta para que no esté basada en opiniones y marqué esa opción. La cuestión es que me surgieron algunas preguntas:

- ¿Con solo pulsar la opción antes mencionada es suficiente o me he dejado algún paso?
- He leído que existen los votos para "reapertura". Desde que la pregunta fue cerrada, ha recibido un voto normal. ¿Son esos votos los que se necesitan para reabrir la pregunta o son otros?

Muchas gracias a todos y ojalá puedan ayudarme a entender estos aspectos, porque ando algo perdido. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Una vez hecha la edición debes esperar a que usuarios con mayor reputación y privilegios revisen esa edición y reabran tu pregunta. Los votos de cierre y reapertura son dadas por usuarios con reputación mayor a 2K (eso creo)

Comment: Se necesitan 3 votos de cierre o reapertura para hacer válida la acción

Comment: Revisando tu pregunta, aún no tiene ningún voto de reapertura, en caso la solicitud de reapertura haya sido denegada verás un mensaje en tu bandeja de entrada.

Comment: Gracias, @Christian, por tus explicaciones. Me quedó más claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Con solo pulsar la opción antes mencionada es suficiente o me he dejado algún paso?

Realizar la edición para resolver el problema, es lo correcto, el resto queda para la gente que hace moderación y revise esta cola (la de reapertura)

> He leído que existen los votos para "reapertura". Desde que la pregunta fue cerrada, ha recibido un voto normal. ¿Son esos votos los que se necesitan para reabrir la pregunta o son otros?

Tal y como crees, son otros. Los votos de reapertura son de una cola diferente, para gente que ha alcanzado cierto puntaje en sus 'Privilegios'

---

Veo que tu pregunta fue editada, pero realmente NO resuelve el hecho de estar basada en opiniones. Paso a explicar un poco para entender el "basado en opiniones"... yo vengo y te digo por ejemplo, 'deprecated' significa obsoleto, en desuso, que se borrará en algún momento, pero hay nuevas opciones para usar lo mismo. Pero luego viene otro y te dice que aun puedes usarlo, y no hay problema hasta que sea borrado, cosa que no pasará. Como ves realmente, ambas respuestas son aceptables, y responden la pregunta, más solo 1 procedimiento es el correcto, el cual es actualizar a lo más nuevo, por diferentes temas, en especial seguridad.

Entonces, al no tener una respuesta concreta, se cierra por el motivo mencionado.

De todos modos, los comentarios recibidos son suficientes para dar a entender como proceder.

BTW, la pregunta no cambió respecto a estar basada en opiniones, y yo que tengo opción de votarla para reapertura pienso que no es apta para reabrirse. Por lo anteriormente mencionado.
No se malentienda el hecho de que una pregunta cerrada es algo "malo", sino que es una medida preventiva del sitio para que las preguntas sean respondidas de manera concreta.

Comment: Hola @Excorpion, muchas gracias por tu extensa respuesta: ahora me quedó mucho más claro cómo funciona el tema de las revisiones. Referente a mi pregunta, tienes toda la razón respecto a lo que dices, y tiene todo el sentido del mundo. En mi caso, ¿lo correcto sería eliminar la pregunta? ¡Gracias otra vez por tu paciencia y ayuda!

Comment: No, como dije, no debes tomar una pregunta cerrada como una pregunta mala. Son diferentes ambas. Esta pregunta solo no es apta bajo los términos del sitio y ya. Borrarla tampoco hará que mejore la situación, por que permanece a pesar de ello.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo. Ahora todo quedó mucho más claro. Haré todo lo posible para hacerlo mejor la próxima vez, ¡gracias! ^^